# Random padding at bottom of page?

Tags: html, css, padding

this is probably extremely simple and I'm probably just looking right over the solution, but here's the problem.

I am trying to add a footer, but for some reason the text of the footer appears around 370px below the main content and I have no idea why. I have checked the height of all previous tags and the padding/margin for them all as well, and there is nothing I see that should be causing an issue.

The html code:

```
<!--Footer-->
<div id="foot_cont">
    <div id="foot_width">
        <div id="footer">
            <p>&copy; Copyright 2014 Legal Consulting, Inc. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#foot_cont  {width:100%;
            clear:both;
            height:100px;
            background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#FFB062,#FF5900);
                             background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#FFB062,#FF5900);
                              background-image:linear-gradient(#FFB062,#FF5900);}   

#foot_width {width:1300px; margin:0 auto;}

#footer {text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow:2px 2px 0px #000000; font-size:36px;
        clear:both;}
```

Here is a link to the website so you can see the issue for yourself.

http://jqwebexamples.com/iAM_Talent/Version3/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS has a rule for `#right_content` that sets the height to `1600px`. Remove it.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I was just being dumb looking over something simple haha, thanks a lot.